# Python evaluation strategy of append and update dict

Tags: python

I've been wondering why this does not work. It intrigued me enough to ask a question.

```
some_list = []
some_dict = {}
some_list.append(some_dict.update({'new_key': 'new_value'}))
print(some_list)
```

result:
`[None]`

I would have thought the inner most strategies are evaluated first.

Comment: It does 'work' though... `dict.update()` returns `None` and changes the dictionary in place. And the dictionary is updated. So everything seems okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `update` mutates the dictionary it is not returning a dictionary. See in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) that this method returns `None`.

If you just want to have one line to solve your problem, you can solve this problem by:

```
some_list.append(dict({'new_key': 'new_value'}, **some_dict))
```

Also to keep in mind:

**In Python 3.5+ you can do:**

```py
>>> params = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> new_params = {**params, **{'c': 3}}
>>> new_params
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

**The Python 2 equivalent is:**

```py
>>> params = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> new_params = dict(params, **{'c': 3})
>>> new_params
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: @SergeyA, thanks I just updated my answer.

Comment: I'd ended up with the same answer when someone replied with the update, does not actually return the updated dict, just mutates the existing dict. this is a nice clean version of what i was attempting. thank you

Comment: @David, you're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

`some_dict.update` updates `some_dict` in-place and returns `None`, it doesn't return the updated `dict`:

```
some_dict.update({'new_key': 'new_value'})
some_list.append(some_dict)
```

However, if you want to keep the old dict unchanged, you can use the following:

```
some_list = []
some_dict = {'old_key' : 'old_value'}
some_list.append({k : v for k, v in [*some_dict.items(), ('new_key', 'new_value')]})
print(some_list)
print(some_dict)
```

Output:

```
[{'old_key': 'old_value', 'new_key': 'new_value'}]
{'old_key': 'old_value'}
```